# Factoring repository method for queries with relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, refactoring

I will explain my 'problem'. I want reduce the number of repository method in my code.

For example, if i have 3 methods :
listChildren => List all children
listChildrenWithParents => List all children with parents relation
listChildrenWithParentsAndParentsType => List all children with parents relation and parents type relation.

The goal would be to have a method that would take the relations to loaded in parameters, and that would dynamically modify the query via the query builder.

Do you have factorization tips to apply to this type of case?

Comment: Could you please add some code examples? Currently it's quite hard to tell what's your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem thanks to this bundle :
https://github.com/Happyr/Doctrine-Specification

It implements the design pattern 'specification' to be able to reuse its code more easily at the level of queries made in the repository